how to extract data from a website where names and other details are a click away?
I want to extract  First Name, Last Name and Email of all the members from this website https://www.iahsp.com/members . how can I do so? the website displays the list of names, then you click the name to get the email of the member. that way it will be very long to copy paste data for 3000 members what is a simplest way to extract data?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have no idea! I just need the simplest web scrapping instruction

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you will find that the data on this website is generated dynamically - this is covered in many other posts on this and other sites. So far as getting around this problem: I have no idea! I just need the simplest web scrapping instruction With respect, users of StackOverflow may be keen to help you solve your problem but they are less than keen to solve it for you. I respectfully suggest that you research this issue and post a new question if you have a specific problem.

This should do the job:
import re
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

AUTHORISATION = 'uYQSxBUgj-FzGSig35rhm8H-wyuit8P2qIRN9R9oFFU.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiMGQxYjlkZTItODJjZi00Mjg4LWIyNzMtMjcyN2YxZDQzNTZiIiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxNGRiZWYwNi1jYzQyLTU1ODMtMzJhNy0zYWJkNDRkYTQ5MDgiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiNjk5NjMxMDgtNWI5MS00YWE2LWJjN2EtZjMwYWEyN2I5MDY3Iiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDI0LTA2LTA3VDA0OjE0OjQzLjk1NloiLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2UsImFpZCI6IjJkOWE4NmQ4LWQ1YTktNDk1Zi1iZmQ3LTljNzcwMTMyNWNhMCIsImJpVG9rZW4iOiI2NDhkYWNlYS1kOTVlLTA4MmUtMGUwOS1kNDJkNTNhZmE1MGMiLCJzaXRlT3duZXJJZCI6IjIxNDJkOGM4LTUzZWItNDUwZS05NGVmLTY2NDk1NTljOTE5MSJ9'

params = {
    'lang': 'en',
    'dateNumberFormat': 'en-us',
    'isPrimaryLanguage': 'true',
    'pageId': 'awj6y',
    'compId': 'TPASection_l94pvaso',
    'viewerCompId': 'TPASection_l94pvaso',
    'siteRevision': '6251',
    'viewMode': 'site',
    'deviceType': 'desktop',
    'locale': 'en',
    'tz': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'regionalLanguage': 'en',
    'width': '1395',
    'height': '8656',
    'instance': 'lzISSV24nhE8UVR4a7tpdOKz3A-vBS56PrcDZjqiqH4.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiOTczYzhjNmEtMzA4OC00ZDU1LTg0YTctY2YzMGE5NmNiNjM5IiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxNGRiZWZkMi0wMWI0LWZiNjEtMzJhNy0zYWJkNDRkYTQ5MDgiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiNjk5NjMxMDgtNWI5MS00YWE2LWJjN2EtZjMwYWEyN2I5MDY3Iiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDI0LTA2LTA3VDAzOjUzOjUwLjI0M1oiLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2UsImFpZCI6IjJkOWE4NmQ4LWQ1YTktNDk1Zi1iZmQ3LTljNzcwMTMyNWNhMCIsImJpVG9rZW4iOiJmZWFhYmQ2Mi02YjE5LTA3ZjMtMzhkZC0zYzNhMGIxNzI2NWUiLCJzaXRlT3duZXJJZCI6IjIxNDJkOGM4LTUzZWItNDUwZS05NGVmLTY2NDk1NTljOTE5MSJ9',
    'currency': 'USD',
    'currentCurrency': 'USD',
    'commonConfig': '{"brand":"wix","host":"VIEWER","bsi":"056bd407-5120-46de-88c2-65e051ee317a|1","BSI":"056bd407-5120-46de-88c2-65e051ee317a|1"}',
    'currentRoute': './members',
    'target': '_top',
    'section-url': 'https://www.iahsp.com/members/',
    'vsi': '1c2dc3c9-baf6-48d0-9844-89cc85557e75',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://members.wixapps.net/_api/members-area/app/members',
    params=params,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

# The data is in a <script> body.
script = soup.select_one("body script")
# Extract relevant part of <script> content.    
match = re.search(r'window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = (\{.*?\});', script.get_text(), re.S)

data = json.loads(match.group(1))

# Get UIDs for members.
#
UID = [member["uid"] for member in data["members"]["map"].values()]

def get_member(uid):
    headers = {
        'authorization': AUTHORISATION,
    }

    json_data = {
        'fileName': 'server/profile.api',
        'functionName': 'getInitialData',
        'args': [
            {
                'showAboutSection': True,
                'showJoinDate': True,
                'showBadgesSection': True,
                'showOverviewSection': True,
                'showBlogPostsSection': True,
                'showCommentsStats': True,
                'showLikesReceivedStats': True,
                'showTopCommentsStats': True,
                'currentMemberId': None,
                'viewedMemberId': uid,
                'postsPerPage': 3,
                'language': 'en',
                'isRTL': False,
                'isMultilingualEnabled': True,
                'isMembersAboutV2Enabled': False,
                'shouldAddPostListToSeoData': False,
                'shouldAddRicosContentToSeoData': False,
                'fetchMemberFieldSet': 'FULL',
            },
        ],
    }

    response = requests.post(
        'https://www.iahsp.com/serverless-yoshi-members-about-ooi/members-about-ooi-93fbd3a84c07138e5078ad7439ce5067/_api_/server/profile.api',
        headers=headers,
        json=json_data,
    )

    member = response.json()["payload"]

    def get_field(field):
        key = "customfields.system."+field

        for field in member["member"]["customProfile"]["fields"]:
            if field["key"] == key:
                return field["value"]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find {field}.")

    print({
        "first": get_field("firstname"),
        "last": get_field("lastname"),
        "email": get_field("email")
    })



for uid in UID:
    # Be gentle.
    time.sleep(5)

    get_member(uid)

Sample output:
{'first': ['Maria Saldña'], 'last': None, 'email': ['sonsureda@yahoo.es']}
{'first': None, 'last': None, 'email': ['paije.shoemaker@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['Janet'], 'last': ['Hunter'], 'email': ['janhuntermaui@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['Steve'], 'last': ['Goldsmith'], 'email': ['steveg@monarchspec.com']}
{'first': ['Sophie'], 'last': ['Lin'], 'email': ['sophiecllin@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['Brian'], 'last': ['Casey'], 'email': ['bcasey8891@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['Susan'], 'last': ['Citty'], 'email': ['susancittyproperties@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['K'], 'last': ['Jaymes'], 'email': ['info@kjaymesquinn.com']}
{'first': ['TIFFANY'], 'last': ['HARDGRAVE'], 'email': ['tiffany@masterpiecestaginganddesign.com']}
{'first': ['Jody'], 'last': ['Lovitt'], 'email': ['2rqc7y52gd@privaterelay.appleid.com']}
{'first': ['Carmel'], 'last': ['Syvertsen'], 'email': ['sales@carolinadreamhome.com', 'carmel@optgreenservice.com']}
{'first': ['Tiffany'], 'last': ['Brayley'], 'email': ['tiffany.brayley@yahoo.com']}
{'first': ['Lisa'], 'last': ['Goodman Age'], 'email': ['giftefhandsinteriors@yahoo.com']}
{'first': ['Bonnie'], 'last': ['Lawless'], 'email': ['bonniejlawless@gmail.com']}
{'first': ['Alisa'], 'last': ['Sparks'], 'email': ['alisa@linden-creek.com']}
{'first': ['Eleonora'], 'last': ['Malatini'], 'email': ['eleonora.malatini@gmail.com']}
{'first': None, 'last': None, 'email': ['esanahuja@mib.isdi.es']}
{'first': ['Linda'], 'last': ['Dunn'], 'email': ['hhsbylinda@gmail.com']}

Note: This solution will not handle the infinite scroll on the main members page. That was not part of the original question and it's a different issue (but not difficult to solve from this starting point!).

Thank you so much!! I really appreciate the time and effort you have put in the response. means alot!! also, I was looking of ways to do it with web scraping. The tools I saw were easy but the website has i frames in it which made it really difficult for me to create a site map.

Hi! I'm confused. The approach in my answer is using web scraping.
